# How to automatically add Double Quotes to enclose a string via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to enclose a search term with Double quotes automatically

For e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="keywords" value="" id="search" size="17" />
<input type="submit" value="Go">
```

a visitor tries to search for a phrase = `long enough` (it contains 2 words with a space in between)

I need the string `long enough` to be passed as `"long enough"` to server side (PHP)

I dont want to tell the visitor to use Double quotes for searching for a phrase, for the visitor the search should be easy.

Presently, when a visitor enters a search term with one word `long` the search results show correct articles.

But when a visitor uses a phrase `long enough` or any other phrase, using a minimum of 2 words, the search results are not accurate as the search take `long enough` as 2 seperate search terms.

For accurate search results, the ExpressionEngine CMS wants the visitor to enter `"long enough"` [any phrase to be enclosed in double quotes]

This is what i want to do automatically, when a visitor searches for one word, it should leave the keyword and let it pass without any quotes, but when a visitor uses 2 or more words, the search form should pass those phrases in Double quotes

---

Code provided by @Jonathon Wisnoski works as i want it, but with one drawback

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function quoteWords() {
            var search = document.getElementById("search_box");
            search.value = search.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, ""); //trim string of ending and beginning whitespace
            if(search.value.indexOf(" ") != -1){ //if more then one word
                search.value = search.value.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, "\"");
            }
        }
  </script>
```

**Issue :** It breaks when manually adding double quotes and pressing submit, one extra double quote is entered at the end. The regex code should see if the double quotes exist, it should not add any thing.

So it makes `"long enough"`  to `"long enough""`

Can anyone check the regex code so see how to solve this issue.

Comment: The term `long enough` should appear on the server as a single string. If you *really* want to wrap that single string in double quotes, so that the quotes are part of the string, just add them to the front and back. Unless I am mis-understanding your question?

Comment: Why can't your PHP script do this? Anything done on the client can be circumvented. Also, you're not doing this in order to interpolate it into a string of SQL, right?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, i have just added more information to the original question.

Comment: Why not do this on the server? Do you have access to the server code to make changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to validate the input to some extent, it might make more sense to do something a little more general - for example, if the user enters "foo "bar", you presumably want it to end up looking like "foo bar".  So instead of:

```
str = '"' + str.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, '') + '"'
```

You might want to do something like:

```
str = '"' + str.replace(/"/g, '') + '"'
```

And that's a lot simpler to look at later.

Comment: This is by far the best solution. Thanks alot. It works perfectly. Ill post here, if an issue arises.

Answer (score 3):

You should really just handle the string *as is* server side. Anything preprocessed with JavaScript can't be relied on.

However, if you did want to do this, there is a non standard `String` method called [`quote()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/quote).

However, because it is non standard, I would use...

```
str = '"' + str.replace(/^"*|"*$/, '') + '"';
```

This strips leading and trailing `"` and then wraps the string again in `"`.

Comment: How would i use the code, i only have HTML search input fields.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I am not a regex expert at all, but this should be better (and you forgot the "g"):
`str = str.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, '"');`

Comment: I incorporated my changed javascript into your code Ibn and added as an answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Jonathon Yeah, it would be, guess I'm not thinking as well as I should be today :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<input type="text" name="keywords" value="" id="search" size="17" />
<input onClick='var search = document.getElementById("search"); search.value = search.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, ""); if(search.value.indexOf(" ") != -1){search.value = search.value.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, "\"")}' type="submit" value="Go">
```

Or with the script in a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function quoteWords() {
        var search = document.getElementById("search");
        search.value = search.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, ""); //trim string of ending and beginning whitespace
        if(search.value.indexOf(" ") != -1){ //if more then one word
            search.value = search.value.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, "\"");
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="text" name="keywords" value="" id="search" size="17">
<input onClick="quoteWords()" type="submit" value="Go">
```

Comment: hmm, well test and get back to you.

Comment: Also note that I changed it so that it should only add teh quotes when more then one word is used.

Comment: @Jonathon Wisnoski, still did not work even with your changed code. 
The quotes are not being passed, they only pass when i add the double quotes manually into the search field `"long enough"`

Comment: Ok, tested and works (had to change how I used quotes in the code).
I did not test for submitting it to a server, but I am sure that will work out fine.

Comment: Not that it should matter, but I never used the single quotes (') this way before, so I should say I tested in Firefox 3.

Comment: still no luck, the search submit is passing the search term without quotes, but when i manually add the quotes, they pass by fine.

Comment: are you getting a javascript error or anything when you run it?

Comment: no, nothing. It just runs fine. It runs just as without the above code.

`8 number of results returned for long enough` this should shows `2 number of results returned for "long enough"` when double quotes are used manually.

Comment: Is it possible to prepend and append the quotes to the search query  just prior to the form submission

Comment: alright i added the script code in the header, what should i replace in the HTML form ?

Comment: Well that is what this should be doing, right before the form is submitted then append/prepend.

I can only say try my second code with the script external to the button as is the only thing I can think of that is going wrong.

Comment: Excellent, the new code worked perfectly Thanks a million.
Is the code safe in terms of security ?

Comment: Also note that the javascript will only work if both the text box has a id of "search" (like in your example) and it is the only (or at least first) html tag that has this id.

Comment: hmm, so should i rename the id to some unique word ? I changed the id to "search_box" and the value of getElementID to "search_box". It works

Comment: Thanks once again, its really appreciated.

Comment: Well I am glad I could help. Well security can mean a lot of things and I am not an expert on any of them.
But this is just normal javascript, which a technically advanced used can change easily but it only runs in his browser so that will not help him get access to your server or anything like that.
So no, it is not insecure.

Comment: @Jonathon Wisnoski ,I tried testing it with manually adding double quotes, for e.g. if someone searches by manually adding the double quotes. 

The results threw off results and added a double quote at the end `"long enough""`

So it breaks when manually adding double quotes and pressing submit, one extra double quote is entered at the end. The regex code should see if the double quotes exist, it should not add any thing.

Comment: As per the discussion here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147609/how-to-remove-duplicate-character-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-regex) it seems this does not work because of on bug in JS regex handling.