# How to remove duplicate character at the end of a string in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with the following regex

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function quoteWords() {
            var search = document.getElementById("search_box");
            search.value = search.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, ""); //trim string of ending and beginning whitespace
            if(search.value.indexOf(" ") != -1){ //if more then one word
                search.value = search.value.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, "\"");
            }
        }
  </script>

<input type="text" name="keywords" value="" id="search_box" size="17">
<input onClick="quoteWords()" type="submit" value="Go">
```

**Issue** : It breaks when manually adding double quotes and pressing submit, one extra double quote is entered at the end. The regex code should see if the double quotes exist, it should not add any thing.

So it makes `"long enough"` to `"long enough""` <- it adds an extra double quote at the end

Can anyone check the regex code so see how to solve this issue.

I only want the double quotes to be inserted once.

Comment: are you just wanting to 'wrap' the value with double quotes if there is more than one word and it has not already been wrapped?

Comment: I am stumped, as far as I knew * always acted greedily, so it should work.

Comment: I believe you should have used `id="search_box"` in the first INPUT element.

Comment: @Matty K you are right, but I tested it after changing them to match and it shows the behaviour he is talking about.

Comment: @Matty K, it was a type from the old code. Both the ids are same

Comment: @Jonathon - Me too, this is an interesting edge case.

Comment: For the record, this also happens in Ruby, using String#gsub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is definitely happening in this line:

```
search.value = search.value.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, "\"");
```

And it is due to the fact that "* matches 0 or more quotes.  However, you presumably wouldn't want to just replace it with "+ since that wouldn't do the job you wanted of double-quoting strings with spaces in them.

You probably just want to do something like this, in two statements:

```
search.value = search.value.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, '')
search.value = '"' + search.value + '"'
```

Part of the key is that there is no 'end of string' character to consume - the regex engine 'just knows' when it is at the end of the string.  So after matching a quote at the end of the string, the cursor just moves to the end of the string, and it finds the empty string one more time before falling off the string.  Thus, the quote at the end of the string is replaced by a quote, and the 'nothing' at the end of the string is also replaced by a quote.

I recommend taking a look at the ECMAScript spec at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf sections 15.5.4.10 and 15.5.4.11 yourself.  However, I've also provided an intuitive illustration of how this works at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/995501).

**EDIT**:

Since people seem confused as to why this would happen, here's something that might help:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6

That's from the documentation for sed, but it explains why combining * and /g is a bad idea.  The fact that JS doesn't just explode when you do that is a mark in its favor.  Note that there are an infinite number of '0 characters' at every position in the string.

Comment: or in one line: `search.value = '"' + search.value.replace(/^"*|"*$/g, '') + '"';`

Comment: I suspect, intuitively but without any justification, that the regexp replacement algorithm is bugging because of the way it replaces `$`.  If you start with no quotes and keep clicking the button, you end up with one, then two quotes, but never more.  Perhaps the global `$` search has a residual second-match somewhere in the regexp engine that causes a second "replacement".

Comment: @Jonathon Basically, since it was globally replacing '0 or more quotes followed by the end of input', it found that twice - one was the quote and the other was the nothing between the quote and the end of input.  My code just strips the quotes if they exist, and then add a nice pair like OP wanted. ETA: the key is the /g

Comment: @Thom does that mean the regexp engine rescans the end-of-string; and so does a match-and-replace to produce the first quote, but then instead of falling off the end of the string (having already consumed the `$`), goes again and matches the end-of-string by itself?

Comment: Oh, that was what I was just thinking. But that is a JS bug right, not how it is supposed to handle it?

Comment: yes, the above solution worked as well. ill keep testing to see if it breaks.

Comment: It seems strange that this works. The greedy `*` should be matching as many repetitions of `"` as possible. I think perhaps the `g` flag is acting an a way you don't expect; you might try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: @Justin Morgan, if i remove g, the double quote is added twice. With g, it works as i want it to work.

Comment: @Justin but without the `g` it would never get past the first character.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the problem isn't the global matching of zero-or-more quotes, since javascript can obviously handle that gracefully in this situation at the start-of-string.  It seems to me that the issue is with it not "consuming" the end-of-string token with the first match.  I can't comprehend why it would make *two* replacements.

Comment: @Matty, you can play around Regex [javascript] here. [link](http://www.rexv.org) You can clearly see that the original code adds one more double quote at the end.

Comment: But I still think it should not be that difficult, and especially in this case it matches $ so the end of string character should be consumed and the program should exit not find another match.

Comment: @Ibn Saeed Yes, I duplicated the issue for myself.  I'm not doubting that the problem occurs, I'm just perplexed as to why.

Comment: @Jonathon - I know, you'd need two different regexes without the `g`. I just meant to try it and see the effect. Check it out: http://refiddle.com/18k and http://refiddle.com/18l

Comment: @Jonathon Yes, rereading my explanation I don't see why any sane engine would work that way, as even global matches don't work recursively.  And it's not some feature of the elements involved; you can put that regex in a function and it will do the same thing to a simple string.

Comment: Seems like the general consensus seems to be that it shouldn't work that way, and I agree. There must be something going on here that none of us are getting.

Comment: Updated.  How this works makes sense now.  Probably a good heuristic for the future is "never globally match 0 or more characters at the end of the string".

Comment: Thanks for the help @Thom Blake and setting up an illustration. @Justin Morgan, @Jonathon Wisnoski

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Thom. But I wonder if the Regex standard would not be better if it was changed to make this case act more intuitively. I wonder if making the end of string character a actual character in the regex function would solve some issues or would it just create other issues?
Meaning `Tokenize the string into characters and append/prepend the start and end special characters and consume them like normal characters, then exit when end is consumed`

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your problem is that you're getting three matches on a string like

> "long enough"

The first match is the start plus the first quote (since regexes are greedy by default). The second match is the end quote and end of string (`$`). However, since the end of string is not an actual character, a third match of 0 characters at the end of string is perhaps occurring.

One possible solution would be to add quotes to the string and then replace one or more quote instead of zero or more quotes:

```
search.value = (search.value + '"').replace(/^"*|"+$/g, "\"");
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Ill keep testing and see if any problem arises

Answer (score 2):

In a regex, `*` matches 0 or more instances of the preceding item, and `+` matches 1 or more instances. Since you're using `*`, the regex matches when there are **0** or more characters that match `\s` in your first regex, and **0** or more `"`s in your second. Changing your `*`s to `+`s should give you the behavior you expect.

Edit: If you want to make it so that the result is surrounded by double quotes if they don't exist at the beginning or ending of the line, use something like `/^[^"]|[^"]$` which reads as "the start of a line followed by any character other than a double-quote or any character other than a double quote followed by the end of a line"

Double Edit: That should probably be `/^[^"\w]|[^"\w]$/` to make sure you don't replace the first and last characters of your match :/

Comment: I think he wants to make sure double quotes exist, only adding them if they don't

Comment: It did not work in my test, and logically it does not make any sense (but then I was involved in a previous iteration of this question so understand more of what is wanted here)

Comment: @Jonathon Wisnoski, i did reply back in the other question. But i think you were not informed by StackOverFlow

Comment: If you enter the text `a b`, then using `+` won't add quotes to produce `"a b"`.  I believe what confused OP - and has subsequently confused me - is why, with the code as-is, entering `a b` and clicking the button twice ends up with the string `"a b"` and then `"a b""`

Comment: @jswolf19 , I think you're right, I updated my answer to reflect that. @MattyK - because it replaces any number of double quotes followed by the end of a line with a double quote, I _think_, but I'm not sure because I'm only interpreting this in my head, that the first single quote is there because the first quote gets stripped and replaced (if that's the case, just entering `example lample` should result in `"xample lample"` ...

Comment: @jeremiahd, i tried your `/^[^"\w]|[^"\w]/` but it removes the whitespace between two words `long enough` becomes `longenough`

Comment: @Ibn Saeed, sorry, I had a typo in the regex, there should be a dollar sign at the end of it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @jeremiahd, `/^[^"\w]|[^"\w]$/` adds double quotes both in the beginning and at the end of the string. So this regex does not solve the issue.

Comment: @Ibn Saeed, I was under the impression that is what you wanted. If you don't want them at the beginning, remove the first half of the regex.

Comment: @jeremiahd, the solution posted above by  @Thom Blake and @jswolf19 has solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` instead of `*`:

```
search.value = search.value.replace(/^"+|"+$/g, '"');
```

Comment: The + breaks my requirement. I need the double quotes to be inserted automatically